# How better is a desktop processor than a mobile processor?

Tags: cpu, tablet, cpu-speed

Inspired by this question and its answer: [What's the difference between mobile and desktop processors?](https://superuser.com/questions/808776/whats-the-difference-between-mobile-and-desktop-processors)

The question and the answer are great to have some insight on the subject. But I'd like to know, in a very aproximative way, the amount of times that a desktop processor could be better than a mobile processor.

Or... other way to put this could be, thinking of actual mobile processors, to which older desktop processor could be similar in performance.

Answer could be something something like: i5 4300U is around 10 times faster than Snapdragon 810

Or... Snapdragon 810 is as powerfull as intel Core Duo XXXX from 2007.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this question. You're fully aware of the fact that Desktop processors are generally more capable in terms of clock speeds than mobile processors. What more is there to it? It almost sounds like some ICT homework you're trying to get us to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to CPU benchmarking... like https://www.cpubenchmark.net/

This will give you an average idea (benchmarking depends on criteria, this website gives a global score, maybe one CPU has better maths than another one, but for example the other one has virtualization support...)

Comment: but I can't see there common ground for comparing movile with desktop...

Comment: If you mean ARM vs Intel (x86), this is harder as the architecture are different. You could compare current Intel mobile CPUs (Atom XXX) with current desktop CPUs.

Comment: No, I mean Qualcomm vs Intel